# Images disappear when coordinates are updated, JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, coordinates

Bah. I figured out the bug. Of course it was absurdly simple. The overridden update under MovingPanelItem needs to be written as follows:

```
@Override
public void update( int x, int y )
{
    xCoord = xCoord + getxStep();
    yCoord = yCoord + getyStep();
}
```

FULL DISCLOSURE: This is homework.

The PROBLEM:
Upon each Key listener event the screen should be updated and the moving objects should move. Currently, while the objects show up initially, if I press the prescribed key they disappear.

Also, all of the PanelItem's are stored in an ArrayList ( in another class ). All of the objects which are not subclasses of MovingPanelItem remain on the screen upon the KeyEvent.

I know I've left a lot to the imagination so if more detail is needed please let me know.

The superclass:

```
public class PanelItem
{
    private Image img;
    protected int xCoord;
    protected int yCoord;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;

    //constructor
    public SceneItem( String path, int x, int y, int w int h )
    {
         xCoord = x;
         yCoord = y;
         setImage( path, w, h );
    }

    public void SetImage( String path, int w, int h )
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    }

    //to be Overriden
    public void update( int width, int height )
    {

    }

}
```

The Subclass:

```
public class MovingPanelItem extends PanelItem
{
    private int xStep, yStep;

    // x & y correspond to the coordinate plane
    // w & h correspond to image width and height
    // xs & ys correspond to unique randomized 'steps' in the for the x and y values

    public MovingSceneItem(String path, int x, int y, int w, int h, int xs, int ys)
    {
        super( path, x, y, w, h);
        setxStep(xs);
        setyStep(ys);
        update( x, y );
    }


    @Override
    public void update( int x, int y )
    {
        this.xCoord = x + getxStep();
        this.yCoord = y + getyStep();
    }
}
```

(In response to Eels)
The panel/window itself is contained within the following class:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {
    protected ArrayList<PanelItem> panelItems;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private long randomSeed;
    private Random random;

    public Panel(JLabel sl) {
        panelItems = new ArrayList<PanelItem>();
        statusLabel = sl;
        random = new Random();
        randomSeed = 100;
    }

    private void addPanel() {
        addPanelItems(10, "Mouse");
    }

    private void addPanelItems(int num, String type) {
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        dim.setSize(dim.getWidth() - 30, dim.getHeight() - 30);

        synchronized (panelItems) {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                int x = random.nextInt(dim.width);
                int y = random.nextInt(dim.height);

                if (type.equals("Person")) {
                    int xs = random.nextInt(21) - 10;
                    int ys = random.nextInt(21) - 10;
                    panelItems.add(new Mouse(x, y, xs, ys));
                 }
             }
             repaint();
         }
    // causes every item to get updated.
    public void updatePanel() {
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        synchronized (panelItems) {
            for (PanelItem pi : panelItems) {
                pi.update(dim.width, dim.height);
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        synchronized (panelItems) {
            for (PanelItem pi : panelItems) {
                pi.draw(g);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

KeyListener class within the test class:

```
private class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter
{
    @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'f') {
            panel.updatePanel();
            panel.repaint();
        }

        // other key events include reseting the panel &
        // creating a new panel, both of which are working.
    }
}
```

Within the above code the only code I'm allowed to change ( & the only code I've written ) is the subclass MovingPanel item.

Comment: The cause of your error is likely not shown in the code you've posted. Are you doing this with Swing? If so, are you calling `getGraphics()` on a component to get a Graphics object anywhere in your code?

Comment: I'm not calling getGraphics(). Although, I've been experimenting with that within my MovingPanelItem class to no avail.

Comment: You're still missing code, in particular your KeyListener and related code which seems to contain the code which causes or at least starts your problems. As an aside, your use of synchronized worries me and for me gives off a funny code smell. This is very unusual to see used this way in a Swing program, especially in the `paintComponent(...)` method or any other method called on the event thread.